# How can I populate the New E-mail Window (Subject and Body fields) using a Userform in MS Outlook?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I regularly issue Purchase Orders to vendors for my job, and either;

- Write the email like a normal person or;
- [Use a macro to open a template that I have generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxVHZ.png)

  ```
      Sub New_Email_from_PO_Template()
      Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
      Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem
      Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set MyItem = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Blah\template.oft")
      MyItem.Display
      End Sub
  ```

My aim is to eliminate the possibility of error by creating a userform, which will then populate a New E-mail window, allowing me to make any desired changes, and add attachments, before manually clicking [Send].

[Included here is a Userform I have created.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXiU5.png)

[image]

The textboxes in the Userform that I have created are as follows;

1. RecipientName
2. PurchaseOrderNumber
3. PurchaseOrderDescription
4. Location
5. ProjectNumber
6. DateRequired

Following [SubmitButton], the data would then be populated into the Subject and Body fields in the New E-mail window.

**Subject Line:**

- "PO# [PurchaseOrderNumber] - [PurchaseOrderDescription] - [Location]"

**Body:**

- "To [Recipient_Name],
  Please find attached Purchase Order (PO# [PurchaseOrderNumber]) pertaining to [PurchaseOrderDescription] for [Location]. Date Required: [DateRequired]
  Thanks and Kind Regards, [User's Outlook Signature]"

The code I have developed is below;

```
Sub ShowPOSubmissionUserform()
POSubmissionEmailGenerator.Show
End Sub

Sub InitialisePOSubmissionUserform()
'Empty ProjectNumberTextbox
ProjectNumberTextbox.Value = ""

'Empty ProjectNameTextbox
ProjectNameTextbox.Value = ""

'Empty PONumberTextbox
PONumberTextbox.Value = ""

'Empty RecipientNameTextbox
RecipientNameTextbox.Value = ""

'Empty DateRequiredTextbox
DateRequiredTextbox.Value = ""
End Sub


Private Sub CloseButton_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim MItem As Object
Dim email_ As String
Dim subject_ As String
Dim body_ As String
Dim attach_ As String
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
email_ = POSubmissionEmailGenerator.ProjectNumberTextbox.Value
subject_ = "Hello this is the subject"
body_ = "Line 1" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Line 3"
'create Mail Item and send it
Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
With MItem
.To = email_
.Subject = subject_
.Body = body_
End With
End Sub
```

At the moment, when pressing submit, NOTHING happens.
What needs to be added to make it at least open the New E-mail window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With MItem
    .To = email_
    .Subject = subject_
    .Body = body_
    .Display '<<  
End With
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim-Williams. Now all that remains is to have my default Outlook signature to appear at the bottom of the text.